# How to Post Ajax data to MVC controller as an Object that have different property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I create search form using ajax post and send filter data as an Object to support case below

x > 100 OR (x > 1 AND x<10) OR (x > 15 AND x < 20)

the filter data is

```
"filters": {
                    "LogicalOperator" : "or",
                    "FilterDescriptors":
                    [
                        { "Member": "x", "Operator": "gt", "Value": 100 },
                        {
                          "LogicalOperator" : "and",
                          "FilterDescriptors":[
                            "Member": "x", "Operator": "gt", "Value": 1,
                            "Member": "x", "Operator": "lt", "Value": 10
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "LogicalOperator" : "and",
                          "FilterDescriptors":[
                            "Member": "x", "Operator": "gt", "Value": 15,
                            "Member": "x", "Operator": "lt", "Value": 20
                          ]
                        },
                    ]
         }
```

In controller I have filters as a parameter

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult GetX(CompositeSearch filters){
      // get data and apply filters
 }
```

in CompositeSearch Class there are

```
 public class CompositeSearch : IFilter {
        public String LogicalOperator {get;set;} 
        public List<IFilter> FilterDescriptors {get;set;}
 }

 public class FilterSearch : IFilter{
        public string Member {get; set;}
        public string Operator {get; set;}
        public object Value {get; set;}
 }
```

the problem is when I send data back and debug parameter filters it is null, my question is how I mapped this object to parameter filter? thank you

Comment: The json input seems not valid, and you can try post data like this `{"LogicalOperator" : "and","FilterDescriptors": [{"Member": "x", "Operator": "gt", "Value": 1},{"Member": "x", "Operator": "lt", "Value": 10}]}` and check if it can be bound to action parameter.

Comment: it contains 2 different kind of object
first it's Composite that is { string:LogicalOperator;object[] FilterDescriptors; 
}
second it's Filter that is {string:Operator;string:Member;string:Value}
the object[] FilterDescriptors can contain both Composite and Filter

Comment: you can't deserialise the same list to two different types, or at least not without writing a lot of custom code in the model binder. You'll need two lists in your model - one to hold the Filter objects and one to hold the Composite objects.

Comment: Also this looks like it might potentially be a recursive structure. Are you allowing a certain maximum depth? Otherwise that could give you problems too.